# ManyToMany в Hibernate пытается добавить существующую запись

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть таблицы User и Project, которые связаны при помощи @ManyToMany через отдельную таблицу

**User**

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_project",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")}
)
private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();
```

**Project**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

**addProject**

```
public void addProject(User user, String name, String text) {

    Project project = new Project(user, name, text);
    projectRepo.save(project);

    Set<Project> projects = user.getProjects();
    projects.add(project);

    user.setProjects(projects);
    //System.out.println(user.getProjects());
    userRepo.save(user);

}
```

Но есть такая проблема. При одиночном вызове метода addProject, добавляющего проект к юзеру, все срабатывает нормально. Но при последующем вызове метода проект корректно добавляется в таблицу с проектами, но при добавлении в таблицу для связи Hibernate пытается добавить юзеру id предыдущего, а не текущего проекта. В итоге выходит ошибка

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "user_project_pkey"
> Подробности: Ключ "(project_id, user_id)=(29, 1)" уже существует.

Не понимаю, в чем я ошибся

Comment: А `User` у вас как в метод попадает?

Comment: @RomanDanilov он попадает через AuthenticationPrincipal

Comment: Попробуйте предварительно вытащить ваши объекты из БД по id